# Call a controller method in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've got an asp.net core application in Visual studio.
In a auto-created view (Events/index.cshtml) I want to call this method from the EventsController.cs

```
public Boolean IsInRole(string Role)
{
    Boolean roleMembership = false;

    if (HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("ID") != null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("Role") == Role)
        {
            roleMembership = true;
        }
    }

    return roleMembership;
}
```

My idea was to call this method at the top of the view with

```
@if(IsInRole("Admin")) {
    show some content
}
```

How can I achieve this task?

Comment: You may be better off in the long run passing this property as part of the model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may move that logic to a separate class. Since this code is using `HttpContext.Session`, it is a good idea to create an interface for your class and let this class be your concrete implementation using `HttpContext.Session`. You can inject the needed implementation in your controller or view using the Dependency Injection framework.

```
public interface IUserAccessHelper
{
    bool IsInRole(string role);
}
public class UserAccessHelper : IUserAccessHelper
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public UserAccessHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public Boolean IsInRole(string role)
    {
        Boolean roleMembership = false;

        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("ID") != null)
        {
            if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Role") == role)
            {
                roleMembership = true;
            }
        }
        return roleMembership;
    }
}
```

Now make sure to to register this in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddTransient<IUserAccessHelper, UserAccessHelper>();
```

Now in the razor view, you can inject this dependency. Yes, DI is possible in views now :)

```
@inject IUserAccessHelper UserAccessHelper
@if (UserAccessHelper.IsInRole("SomeRole"))
{
    <h2>In Role</h2>
}
else
{
    <h2>Not in Role</h2>
 }
```

You can inject the same `IUserAccessHelper` inside your controller via constructor injection.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserAccessHelper userAccessHelper;
    public HomeController(IUserAccessHelper userAccessHelper) 
    {
        this.userAccessHelper = userAccessHelper;
    }
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
       // you can use this.userAccessHelper.IsInRole("abc")
       // to do  :return something
    }
}
```

Since you are injecting the needed implementation via dependency injection, now you can unit test your controller method. **Your controller code does not have any tight coupling to `HttpContext` now**. You can create a `MockUserAccessHelper` (which does not use HttpContext) for your unit tests and use that as needed.

Comment: Other than passing the data in as part of the model, this is the best way by far of doing this in ASP.Net Core.

Comment: You saved my day. I still didn't know DI can be used in Views.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a generic method not specific to any controller, move it into a separate class.

Then you can reference that class's namespace in your view with a `@using` directive (almost exactly like you would in a .cs file), and then call the method.

Comment: The method would need to be made static.

Comment: @AshleyMedway it would certainly be logical to make it static, but there's no requirement to. There's nothing to stop you instantiating a class in Razor code.