# MVC Google map API key reading from database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I have google map on my web page. It works fine.

However, I hard code the map key like google example

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

You_API_KEY is hard code value.

First of all, I read various pages. I know I cannot hide this key.
However, I do want to use variable such as instead of hard code the key. if the key changes, I have to change javascript. Plus on the CS code, I also call this function. it is better to save in the variable instead of hard code everywhere.

How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: you can inject that value by replacing it with a C# variable/expression. Ex ( `js?key=@(someC#ExpressionWhichReturnsKey)&callback=initMap`)

Comment: @Shyju: Please use the answer mechanism to answer questions so they can be accepted and closed.

Answer (score 3):

The script tag is included in the razor view, which means you can execute some C# expression to get the api key value. Your server code can read this value and pass it to the view.

The most simple way is passing it via ViewBag. You can set the api key value to the viewbag dictionary in your action method

```
ViewBag.MyApiKey = "123";
```

And in the layout view, you can use this

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=@(ViewBag.MyApiKey)&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

I just hard coded the value to "123". You may read the actual value from your storage (db table/config file etc) and set that value to the viewbag dictionary.

If you go with the ViewBag approach, i would recommend writing a custom filter which does that, so that you can globally apply this filter instead of setting the viewbag dictionary item in each action method.

```
public class LoadApiKeys : ActionFilterAttribute, System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var apiKey = "G12345";
        //to do : Read from db instead of hard coded value
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.GoogleApiKey =apiKey;
    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
    }
}
```

and register this filter globally so it will be executed for all calls

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new LoadApiKeys());
    }
}
```

Assuming `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters` is called from `Global.asax`

Basically you can execute any C# expression which returns a string value and use that value in your script tag when it is inside a razor view. For example you can write a helper method which does that

```
public static class WebExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetMyApiKey()
    {
        return "GetApiKeyFromDbAndReturnThat";
    }
}
```

and in the razor view

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=@(WebExtensionMethods.GetMyApiKey())&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

If you are using Asp.Net core 2.0, you can do dependency injection in views. With this, you may create a service which can return the key and inject it to the view and use it. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635284/call-a-controller-method-in-a-view/47635439#47635439) for sample code on DI in views.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Actually, I tried with enclosing with (), and it failed, so I removed it, and it works. Sorry, I was testing my program and forgot about this. Your C# sample is very good. I did not bother to create filter